# Vertical align of HTML table cell when there is div inside

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML table. I want to use only one column. The word "Name" in my table cell should be vertically centered, but when I add a div with numbers and linebreaks, the text "Name" is not vertically centered anymore.

How could I make vertical align work again?

I'm looking for a cross browser solution without JavaScript/jQuery.

```html
<table style="width: 100px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: middle">Name<div style="float: right">1<br />2<br />3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use `float` but `display`. `inline-block` element can be vertically aligned from the `baseline`

```html
<table style="width: 100px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: middle">Name<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">1<br />2<br />3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

guess from your comment

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

td>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table {
background:linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%)
```

```html
<table style="width: 400px">
  <tr>
    <td>Name
      <div>1<br />2<br />3</div>
    </td>
    <td>Name
      <div>1<br />2033</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how i would do this :

```css
  td,
th {
  vertical-align: middle
}

table {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
```

```html
<table style="width: 400px">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>1<br />2<br />3
    </td>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>1<br />2033
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works fine, but if I make the table wider and add an another cell, they are not equally vertically centered.

Comment: At the moment your "guess from your comment" is the best way. Anyway, I'm not sure if browsers will vertically center the texts 100% same way when using inline-blocks inside table cells.

Comment: @xms see https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align to understand about vertical-align and how to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the CSS styling using a flexbox. Is this what you need?

```html
<table style="width: 100px">
  <tr>
    <td style="display:flex; align-items: center">Name<div>1<br />2<br />3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks fine, but I'm pretty sure that flex is not a cross browser solution.

Comment: Depends on how far you want to go back in time ;) I only have Edge myself and that's not a problem.